# How to build fast visible light detector

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, phototransistor, ldr, light-sensor

I need a circuit which can detect flickering of light too fast. I have Digital LDR Module which is too slow can I replace LDR with L14G2.

Digital LDR Module -

[image]

Digital LDR Circuit -

[image]

Can we replace LDR with L14G2 or PT334-6C in above circuit.

Comment: reverse biased photodiode in a transimpedance amp

Comment: You need to provide links to the manufacturers' datasheets for the "L14G2" and "PT334-6c".

Comment: How fast do you mean? Most people will think 10-100s of MHz, but the L14G2 is KHz.

Comment: What sort of 'visible' light are you trying to detect, and why?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I want to detect 5mm white LED with >9600 baud rate. I would like to replace with [link](http://www.vishay.com/photo-detectors/list/product-84768)

Comment: The common light-dependent resistor (CdS) is SLOW to turn off, so for speed higher than ~1 kHz, it's troublesome.

Comment: your "need" is not defined in good Engineering specs. so answer to your question is no  unless you are an expert

Comment: Final project -> https://github.com/Sathvik-Rao/Li-Fi_Messenger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you cam replace the CDS sensor with a phototransistor. The Collector needs to go to pin 2 (+) and the Emitter to pin 1 (-). To improve response time you should also remove C2.

If you find the transistor is not sensitive enough then you can increase the value of R1 to eg. 100k. This will slow the response due to the longer time constant of the larger resistance with capacitance of the transistor etc., but should still be good for significantly faster than 9600 baud.

Alternatively swap the positions of the phototransistor and R1. This will allow the comparator to detect the lower voltage produced by lower light levels (the way the circuit is currently configured it cannot detect less than ~1.5V across R1 because the LM393's common mode input range only extends to ~1.5V below Vcc).

Comment: can i use [link](https://robu.in/product/pt334-6c-5mm-phototransistor-pack-of-10) as phototransistor or buy photodiode to implement it on same pcb as [link](https://www.sunrom.com/p/light-sensor-module-photodiode)

Comment: It should work, though it is more sensitive to infrared than visible light so you might consider using an infrared rather than white LED. BTW I tested a TEPT4400 with a superbright white LED and got a good signal with only 2mA of  LED current.  Pulse rise/fall time was ~20us with a 10k load resistor.

Comment: TEPT4400 is basically the same as the other devices in that range (just a different package) so use whatever variant you can get. The PT334-6c should also work. It has lower sensitivity but faster response.

Comment: I would go with TEPT5600/TEPT4400 because sensitivity(error free) is important  than speed. I searched TEPT5600 datasheet but couldn't able to find it's rise/fall time.

Comment: can you please test with TEPT5600 also on same circuit

Comment: Sorry I can't test the TEPT5600 because I don't have one. However the electrical specs are identical to the TEPT4400 so it should work the same. Note that sensitivity will vary depending on which 'bin' it comes from. When manufactured the sensitivity varies widely, and the manufacturer wants to sell all of them so you get what they send you (unless the supplier lets you select one from a particular bin, which will probably cost extra).

Comment: Although one "could" make 9600 baud work with a TEPT440, or a phototransistor, but I would never recommend it, with 200uA just from stray room light. or huge gain tolerances affects threshold in a PT (-1

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I agree, but that's what the OP wants. Perhaps he needs to use a white LED for some reason, and perhaps stray room light isn't a problem for him. Many years ago I added a remote mute circuit to my TV using a photocell and incandescent torch. It worked fine because the photocell was mounted at the end of a narrow tube, and the room needed to be fairly dark to get a good picture on that old TV!

Comment: @BruceAbbott  Yes I am a familiar with that , I used recessed holes with IRDA receivers to detect a resistor lead in the bottom of a bask of a shopping cart in a 1m aisle using only IR LED's to detect a shopping cart and goods in BoB  (laser like object resolution using 5 mm LEDs

Comment: @BruceAbbott https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/472290/220380

Answer (score 1):

Too bad you are a decade late. Sharp invented a 5mm Light Detector that spanned > 4 decades of visible light with a lens that matched the human eye CIE color-corrected. that didn't sell even so precise and cheap, even Vishay couldn't market it, so it went obsolete.

There are others http://global.sharp/products/device/lineup/selection/pdf/opto_det201809_e.pdf

How fast??   **3 to 5 us rise time**

Or faster?

Keep in mind, Light sensors are current sources and high impedance so the lower the current and higher the impedance into some capacitance results in slower rise time.

Comment: I want to detect 5mm white LED with >9600 baud rate. Can i use [link](http://www.vishay.com/photo-detectors/list/product-84768)

Comment: Maybe .   How will you block daylight ?   Aim it?  TIA gain?

Comment: Old technology was called IRDA ... search that

Comment: does this work https://www.sunrom.com/p/light-sensor-module-photodiode

Comment: No I said **Search for IRDA**  ( 9600 data is not just a fast flicker of light.)  http://www.actisys.com/techSupport-mob.html

Comment: We call your question XY because you said X but you meant Y=I want to design a 9600 optical link for a distance of ??  meaning wrong assumptions and description of problem. Y problem is not well defined by   X